# How can I change a friend's photo on Message+ with my Galaxy S21?

Tags: sms, photos

I somehow placed my own picture on message threads from a friend. How can I restore his picture? I have a Galaxy S21 FE 5G.

Comment: Please provide more information on your phone, the OS, the messaging app, and what picture are you talking about.

Comment: By Message+, did you mean [Verizon's own messaging app](https://www.vzmessages.com/introduction/)?